# Domain Validated/Level SSL Certificate with Green Bar in Browser

Tags: security, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

We are a startup from India, yet to register as a company. 
However, in order to launch , we need to put up SSL certificate on our platform as we deal with critical info. Though the main concern is to have a Green Bar so that most of the browsers let the users in without a warning or anything. Is it possible to get a Domain Validated SSL Certificate that comes with a Green Bar?

Answer (score 1):

The Green Bar will only happen with EV (Extended Validation) certificates, not with DV (Domain Validated). There is nothing you can do against this because this behavior is built into the browsers itself.

Answer (score 0):

As Steffen points out, the green bar is a feature of Extended Validation certificates. These require additional validation of you're business by the certificate supplier, and tend to be significantly more expensive than domain validation certificates (probably to pay the additional staff required to do checks).

There's no way to get the green bar with domain validated certificates. If you could, it would entirely invalidate the existence of the EV certs.

Answer (score -2):

This is very simple, you have to purchase a ssl certificate from your hosting provider and then copy the code in the ssl certificate manager into your hosting and put that code into your index page. To redirect the site from http: to https: ask to the hosting provider to redirect it and they will give you the redirection code.
If you site is built on a CMS platform, let me know. It has a different method I can help you if you still need help.